# Custom XHR Callbacks Handler

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a small typescript http library for my friend to simplify the http requests a little bit. I want my friend to be able to send Asynchronous POST requests using method `post()` from the `Http` object I've created.

I want to accomplish something similar to `subscribe()` method in Angular 2. What I mean is I want to create a function, which would be responsible for callbacks (3 types - success, error, complete) and I would use it on my Http's post() method. Here is what I have until now.

Basically here is the written idea:

Http:

```
import { IHeader } from 'interfaces';
import { SubscribeAble } from 'subscribeAble';

class Http {
    http: XMLHttpRequest;

    constructor() {
        this.http = new XMLHttpRequest;
    }

    post(url: string, data: Object, headers?: Array<IHeader>) {
        this.http.open('POST', url);

        if(headers) {
            for(let header of headers) {
                this.http.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
            }
        }

        this.http.send(JSON.stringify(data));

        return new SubscribeAble(this.http);
    }
}
```

SubscribeAble:

```
export class Subscribe {
    http: XMLHttpRequest;

    constructor(http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    subscribe(success: (success) => void, error?: (error) => void, complete?: () => void) {
        this.http.onload = success;
        if(error) { this.http.onerror = error; }
        if(complete) { this.http.onreadystatechange = complete; }
    }
}
```

What I need now is the idea of how to inject the data to functions in `subscribe()` method... a bit more simple: I want 'success' variable to have `this.http.response` value in function `(success) => {}`. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to repair the `subscribe` method. I used callbacks to achieve what I wanted to. Here is the code:

```
subscribe(success: (success) => void, error?: (error) => void, complete?: () => void) {
    let callback = (cb: (res) => void) {
        return callback(this.http.response);
    }

    this.http.onload = () => {
        return callback(success);
    }
    if(error) { 
        this.http.onerror = () => {
            return callback(error);
        }
    }
    if(complete) { this.http.onloadend = complete; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
subscribe(success: (success) => void, error?: (error) => void, complete?: () => void) {
   this.success = success;
   this.error = error;
   this.complete = complete;

   this.http.onload = this.onload;
   if(error) { this.http.onerror = this.onerror; }
   if(complete) { this.http.onreadystatechange = this.oncomplete; }
}

onload() {
   if (this.http.status === 200) {
      this.success(this.response);
   } else {
      if (this.error)
        this.error(this.http.statusText);
      }
   }
}
```

you set the functions the user send you in subscribe as class variables, and call them with the data you want to send as their parameters.

and you can create the `onerror` and `oncomplete` method for the other 2 functions